# 1999 Chevy Cavalier transmission-to-engine support brace

Tags: engine, chevrolet, automatic-transmission, cavalier

I'm removing the engine from a 1999 Chevy Cavalier (2.2L bi-fuel). Step 28 in the service manual in `Remove the transmission-to-engine support brace.`

I've looked all around the transmission-engine connection and could not find anything that appears to hold the transmission the the engine aside from the 6 bolts directly connecting them. Where will I find this brace?

[image: engine-transmission flywheel]

[image: engine-transmission rear]

Addendum:

I tried adding the following to the answer, but lack edit rights.

@Ben located the bracket for me. The easiest access to the bolts is through the right wheel well using a 13mm socket and long extension.

[image: transmission bolts]

[image: engine bolts]

Removing the oil filter would likely make access even easier, but mine seems seized.

Comment: maybe it was removed at one point it should be on the under side bolted to the block and transmission I believe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was wrong about the placement of the bracket. In some cars they have a bracket that goes from the bell housing to around the oil pan.

I believe in your second picture it's the bracket on the left hand side.

[image]